# Do I evaluate "(require 'eclimd)" successfully?

Tags: elisp

In a buffer in fundamental mode, I type Ctrl-x Ctrl-e at the end of the line

```
(require 'eclimd)
```

the minibuffer at the bottom says `eclimd`. Does it mean I run the command successfully?

If yes, why does `require` output `eclimd`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It did not give you an error message, so you successfully `require`d it.  Have a look at the [manual on named features](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Named-Features.html) and `require`'s docstring; they indicate that, when you `(require FEATURE)`, "normally the return value is FEATURE."  That is, it returns the symbol naming the feature you just `require`d.